# How to remove commits from the middle without affecting history?

Tags: git

I need to delete some commits from the remote, the ones which show after merging sometimes.

```
Mar 23   abcd999    some message
Mar 11   abcd123    some message
Feb 12   xyze456    merged in feature (not required)
Feb 6    98y65r4    merged in develop (not required)
Jan 20   987xcrt    2nd commit
Jan 5    45345rt    initial commit
```

However, I don't want the history to be changed. I have tried various methods, but all change the history and the `abcd123`, `abcd999` commits shows as commited 5 minutes ago.

I am able to create the branch with correct commits and the correct time is shown when I execute : `git log`

But when I push, the top commits take the current time. I have tried doing:

```
git push -f
git push --force
```

But it hasn't worked. How can I do this?

Clarification : By keeping the commit history, i mean the date of the commit. I tried changing date by using --date. But the commit date still shows the latest when i push. My repo is on aws codecommit. Can this be the issue? In git log, all dates shown are as per requirement.

Comment: It's impossible.

Comment: you can create new commit which will reverse problematic commit. But as point out it is impossible remove commit without changing history. After all this commit is part of history.

Comment: A quick workaround for you is to edit commit date after the deletion of a commit. Use the `--date` argument. This is bothersome, but definitely possible.

Comment: @TimmyChan this will change history too.

Comment: There is a logical contradiction here; one cannot both change history (I need) and not change history (I don’t want). As such the question is missing some relevant detail, imposible, or unclear.

Comment: @MarekR it depends on what he meant. Seems to me that he wanted to keep the original commit date of the succeeding commits. Thus, in a sense, keep the history. One cannot change the history of the real world, of course.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to delete some commits... However, I don't want the history to be changed.

Deleting commits *does* change history. You cannot want to delete commits without wanting to change history. It's metaphysically impossible.

> But when I push, the top commits take the current time

Correct. That's because you also cannot *change* an existing commit. But parentage is a feature of a commit. Therefore if you do delete a commit, every subsequent commit (commits with the deleted commit as an ancestor) is *replaced* with a new and different commit (because parentage cannot be changed). So yes, it does have a new date, because it is in fact a new commit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i do git log, i see all the commits with the original date, means the past dates. Should it not show as recent commit in git log too?

Comment: You might be asking now a question about how GitHub behaves (or whatever "the remote" is), rather than how Git behaves. But that is not the question you _originally_ asked (though it may be what you _meant_ to ask!). If that's the real question, I'll delete my answer, because it isn't at all what you really want to know.